# Glassfish Parando

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-aws, glassfish

Amigos, estou enfrentando um problema.
Do nada, minhas aplicações param de funcionar.

Utilizo o Glassfish 4.1.1, rodando em um servidor AWS, com 4 aplicações publicadas, sendo 3 aplicações Java Web e 1 aplicação web service.
Todas as aplicações estão rodando normalmente, quando, de repente, do nada param, sem nenhum registro de erro nos logs do Glassfish.  Simplesmente param.

Para retornar à funcionar, preciso reiniciar o Glassfish.

Este servidor AWS tem 2 núcleos com 4GB RAM, porém em meus monitoramentos, a memória RAM trabalha no máximo com 65% de sua capacidade total.
O uso do CPU também trabalha com no máximo 45% de sua capacidade.

No mesmo servidor rodo o MySQL.
A configuração para o MySQL é:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1932735283

max_connections         = 302

wait_timeout            = 10800

interactive_timeout     = 100
```

Porém o MySQL não para de funcionar.

Referente ao Glassfish, as configurações que utilizo são:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

-Xmx1024m
```

Por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar com este problema?
Muito obrigado

Comment: O primeiro passo seria habilitar o log do Glassfish e das aplicações para ver o que está acontecendo, sem isso é meio difícil

Comment: @md_rss, muito obrigado pelo seu retorno.  Infelizmente meu conhecimento com o Glassfish é muito baixo e não sei como fazer estes procedimentos.  Por favor, poderias me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Verifique os logs e poste aqui, devem estar em: `/YOUR_GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/`

Se não tiver logs você pode habilitar, ou aumentar o nível de log:

Configuration -> Server Config -> Logger Settings.

Então selecione: 'Logger Levels'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
retirado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184432/how-do-i-set-logging-level-in-glassfish

Note:
Os diferentes níveis de log em ordem são:

SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, and FINEST.